# Не могу придумать алгоритм для задачки - максимальный профит от торгов альткоины

Tags: python, алгоритм, олимпиада

> Паша сильно увлекся криптовалютами. Недавно он наткнулся на альткоины —
> очередную криптовалюту.
>
> Сейчас у Паши S рублей. Сегодня начинаются торги альткоинами, они будут
> длиться n дней. Каждый день торгов Паша может либо купить сколько-то
> альткоинов, либо продать какое-то количество альткоинов из тех, которые
> у него есть, либо ничего не делать. В i-й день можно купить один
> альткоин за ai рублей или продать один альткоин за bi рублей.
>
> Какое максимальное количество рублей может оказаться у Паши под конец
> торгов?
>
> Формат входных данных В первой строке вводятся два целых числа n и S
> (1≤n≤50000,1≤S≤1000000) — продолжительность торгов в днях и кол-во
> рублей у Паши в начале торгов соответственно.
>
> Последующие N строк содержат информацию о каждем дне торгов. В i-й из
> этих строк вводятся два целых числа ai и bi (1≤bi≤ai≤1000000) — цена
> покупки и продажи альткоина соответственно.
>
> Формат выходных данных Выведите максимальное количество рублей,
> которое может оказаться у Паши под конец торгов.

```
входные данные   
3 1000 
100 99 
110 105 
90 80 
выходные данные 
1050 

входные данные   
3 15 
4 3 
9 4 
9 8 
выходные данные 
27
```

Пытался решить под конкретные примеры, но дальше ответы неверные WA. Какие примеры могут быть?

```
n, s = map(int, input().split())
delcount = 0
buy = []
sell = []
buycount = 0
for i in range(n):
    a, b = map(int, input().split())
    buy.append(a)
    sell.append(b)
for i in range(n):
    if buy.index(min(buy)) > sell.index(max(sell)):
        buy.remove(min(buy))
        delcount += 1
    else:
        buycount = s // min(buy)
        s -= (s // min(buy)) * min(buy)
        s += buycount * max(sell)
        break
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте

1. 3 1000
2. 9 1
3. 10 2
4. 300 4

Comment: >>> 1000//9
111
>>> 111*4
444
>>> 444+1
445  это норм

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).